# Будут ли безопасны запросы?

Tags: mysqli, php, sql, mysql

У меня множество обращений к БД, и писать в каждой функции подготовленный запрос с кучей параметров, не очень мне удобно.

Мой вариант такой, создаю функцию к примеру на выборку:

```
private function select($table_name) 
{
    $this->link->query('SELECT * FROM \''.$table_name.'\'');
}
```

*Всё, передаем что хотим, тут инъекции быть не может, по-моему.*   
**Таким же способом для INSERT & UPDATE.** 
Шаблонов нету, места раза в 2 меньше занимает, так в чем же его недостаток? в таком способе запросов?

Т.е к любому запросу добавляем экранированные кавычки, и всё, это уже никак не может быть запросом, если и будет запрос, он уйдет в какую-то запись в БД вместе с текстом, но не в SQL.

Comment: > Всё, передаем что хотим, тут инъекции быть не может, по-моему. 

    $table_name = 'users\'; DROP DATABASE dbname; --эж

Comment: тексты запросов прямо в коде программы да еще с конкатенацией значений параметров?  Даже если не говорить о безопасности, это просто говнокод, имхо

Comment: Вообще вам просто query builder нужен и все.

И еще забавный факт: запрос-то не пройдет в таких кавычках.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, такие запросы не будут безопасным. Вам надо экранировать любую переменную, при генерации запроса строкой. Но лучше использовать параметры.